# some questions on $k$-sheeted covering of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth, projective curve of genus $g \geq 11$. Let $X$ be another curve such that $C$ is a $k$-sheeted covering of $X$ ( I hope this means there exists a finite degree $k$ morphism from $C$ to $X$, please correct me if this definition is wrong i.e. there are some extra conditions on fiber). Then I have the following questions :

$(1)$ If $X=\mathbb P^1$, then can we conclude that $C$ admits a $g^1_k$ ?

$(2)$ If $X$ is another curve of small genus (say $\leq 3$) and $k=2$. Then can we use the information of genus of $X$ to comment on genus of $C$?

I have seen such a result on genus  for degree  $2$ finite morphsim. Can anyone indicate a reference which discusses the general proposition involving genus and finite morphism?

$(3)$ Assume that $C$ is a smooth complete intersection of two hypersurfaces of degree atleast $4$ in $\mathbb P^3$. In this situation can we have $k=3$ and $X$ an elliptic curve?

can we use some invariants to understand this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, by the definition of a $g_k^1$.
2. The result you are looking for is the (Riemann-)Hurwitz formula. Let $f: C\to X$ be your finite separable morphism of degree $k$ and let $R$ be the ramification divisor. Then
   $$ 2g(C)-2=k(2g(X)-2)+\text{deg } R.$$ If $k=2$, we have $2g(C)=4g(X)-2+\text{deg } R.$

You can find the Hurwitz formula in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry (I think it's in paragraph IV.2) or in Ravi Vakil's 'The Rising Sea' (Theorem 21.7.3 in the 2017 version).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have the following queries : $(1)$ Could you please direct me to a reference which defines $k$-sheeted covering explicitly, Everywhere I have seen  it's mentioned but without being defined $(2)$ For Riemann-Hurwitz Theorem don't we need to check that the morphism is separable?

Comment: @New For (1) I can't, I don't think I've ever seen this term used that way in a book. I am just used to people saying '$k$-sheeted covering' as a shorthand for 'degree $k$ finite morphism$. As for (2), you are absolutely correct, I just forgot about it since it's automatic in characteristic 0.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov, In your formula I think $g(X)$ and $g(C)$ are interchanged and therefore these arguments don't work. Do the conclusions still hold though?

Comment: @HARRY You are absolutely correct, I did mix up $X$ and $C$. I did feel that something was off when writing this... I don't know the answer to 3 now.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov, Can we say anything about $\text{deg}(R)$ when the map is a $k$ sheeted covering and the curve is complete intersection as before. Can it happen that $f$ is unramified or these hypothesis restrict $ \text{ deg} (R)$ somehow?

Comment: @New You can still apply the Riemann-Hurwitz formula. You will get the exact value of $\text{deg}(R)$. In your case 3 you will get that it's at least 62. So the problem is then whether there are any morphisms with such a ramification divisor from a complete intersection such as yours.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov, exactly. But unfortunately I don't know how to proceed in order to obtain a contradiction ( or otherwise). Perhaps there is some other way to compute exactly ( or to give a bound) the value of $ \text{ deg}(R)$